# How to use css3 'flexbox' to make a layout like this?

Tags: css, flexbox

Here is a `div` container. I know how to easily use display and width to make it look like this, but how to use `CSS3` `flexbox` to make 4 buttons layout as follow?

[image]

```css
.container {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 10px;
}
button {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
button:nth-of-type(2),
button:nth-of-type(3) {
  width: 49%;
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <button>Button1</button>
  <button>Button1</button>
  <button>Button1</button>
  <button>Button1</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Always show ur efforts with the thing you need help with and you will get help. Your questions does not show any effort other than the lovely image :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `flex-flow:row wrap` and make the top / bottom buttons take twice the space

```css
   div, div *{box-sizing:border-box;}
div{display:flex;flex-flow:row wrap;padding:50px;}
div button{flex:1;}
div button:first-child,
div button:last-child{flex:2 100%}
```

```html
<div>
  <button>1</button>
  <button>2</button>
  <button>3</button>
  <button>4</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Once I add padding to container div, it just breaks the layout though.

Comment: @ZhenyangHua you need `box-sizing:border-box` so that the padding does not get added to the width.

Comment: What if I want to add padding to the container div (not the button)? that seems to break the flex layout.

Answer (score 1):

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <button>Button1</button>
    <button>Button2</button>
    <button>Button3</button>
    <button>Button4</button>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
    background-color: blue;
    width: 200px;
    padding: 10px;
}

button { margin: 5px 0; }

button:nth-of-type(1), 
button:nth-of-type(4) { flex: 1 1 100%; }

button:nth-of-type(2),
button:nth-of-type(3) { flex: 0 1 45%; }
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/u5qo37ec/)